# IE9 download bar vs download dialog

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, download, internet-explorer-9

Sometimes when I download something in IE9, I get this download bar

[image: IE9 bar]

And sometimes I get this dialog

[image: IE9 dialog]

Can I force IE to use one or the other? I would like to have only the dialog if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a user you cannot do that, no. As far as I know the dialog only pops up if a web site opens another tab which leads to a download (something along those lines, at least). So the website developer can change the behaviour, even though I think that's more by accident than intentionally.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to depend on 3 things:

1. Is the download a direct link to a file (e.g. http://foo.com/a.zip) or not (http://foo.com/dl?id=123)?
2. Does the server send `Content-Disposition: attachment` with the header or not?
3. Is it a "special" file type from MS/IE's point of view? This appears to include office files like `.docx` etc (if office is installed), `.cab` files, `.lnk` files, and almost certainly more

The behaviour I observe is as follows:

- The **dialog** is shown if: 1) it is a direct link 2) it *doesn't* have `Content-Disposition: attachment` *and* 3) it is one of MS's favoured file types.
- In any other combination, it appears to use the **bar**.
- Note on point 3: it depends on whether you have a local handler installed for that file type, hence why if you don't have office installed then office files will download with the bar.

This was all determined experimentally. I then found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822625/why-is-this-save-dialog-appearing-for-some-users-of-internet-explorer) which seems to back up some of the above.